# Why i get sha256 verifying error by pulling dotnet docker image?

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, debian, docker-registry

i try to pull dotnet 3.1 on Debian 9 machine with docker and got this error:

```
Error pulling image configuration: image config verification failed for digetst sha256:<some sha256 code>
```

docker comand:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim
```

also i tryed to pull with sha256 like this: `docker pull <dotnet tag>@sha256:<sha256 tag>`

Comment: Are you using Debian 9 on VM?

Comment: it is physical machine and i connect over ssh